Let $h:\{0,1,\ldots,10\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(0)=0, h(10) = 10$. Find $h(1)$ if $2[h(i)-h(i-1)]=h(i+1)-h(i)$
The question:
Let $h:\{0,1,\ldots,10\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(0)=0, h(10) = 10$. Find $h(1)$ if $2[h(i)-h(i-1)]=h(i+1)-h(i)$
My attempt:
\begin{align*}
3h(10) &= 30 \\
3h(9) &= h(10)+2h(8)\\
3h(8) &= h(9)+2h(7)\\
&.\\
&.\\
3h(1) &= h(2)+2h(0)
\end{align*}
Now, I added both sides to get the equation:-
$2[h(1)+h(9)] = h(0)+h(10)$. But this didn't help.
Also, could you suggest how to approach this general type of recursive problems, some problems include finding limits. What the general way of approaching/thinking process in these types of problems.

Do you know what a  telescopic sum is?

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with that term.

Hint: $x_n:=h_{n+1}-h_n=2^nx_0$ and $10=x_9+x_8+\dots+x_0$.

The recursion $h_{n+1}=3h_n-2h_{n-1}$ can be solved in general by standard means.  You'll get two paramaters which you can solve for using the two given points.

@AnneBauval Thanks a lot, I managed to do it with your hint.

@lulu Thanks a lot. I will check out the link

Does this answer your question? Solve the difference equation $x_n-4x_{n-1}+3x_{n-2}=0$, $x_0 = 2$, $x_1 = 5$ Apply the method of this answer. (The coefficients in your case are of course not the same.)

@AnneBauval Actually, I used what you suggested in your previous comment. I will check this link and see how much this helps me in dealing with recurrence questions in general. Thanks for the link.

Let $h(1)-h(0)=d,$ then $h(2)-h(1)=2d \dots h(10)-h(9)=2^9d$
$$\implies h(10)-h(0)=d(1+2+4+8\dots 2^9) \implies d=\frac{10}{2^{10}-1}$$
So,
$h(1)=\frac{10}{2^{10}-1}$
